# UITableViewScrollPositionNone does not scroll the table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

When using `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`, I am passing in `UITableViewScrollPositionNone`. Despite the name, I am expecting the tableview to scroll when necessary so that the row is visible (and not scroll if it is already visible).

> UITableViewScrollPositionNone -
>   The table view scrolls the row of interest to be fully visible with a minimum of movement. If the row is already fully visible, no scrolling occurs. For example, if the row is above the visible area, the behavior is identical to that specified by UITableViewScrollPositionTop. This is the default.

However, I am finding that the table view does not scroll at all. If I use `UITableViewScrollPositionTop` or `UITableViewScrollPositionBottom`, the table view scrolls as expected.

Can it be possible that the documentation for this is incorrect? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The documentation is definitely correct. Are you instantiating a scrollTo animation?

Comment: I am just calling [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:myPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES] in all three examples.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your bounds have been set properly?

Comment: I'm using a UITableViewController

Comment: Of course, but your UITableViewController has bounds, and although you may be able to view it, the bounds may be offset somehow by another class.

Comment: I see. No, I'm using a pretty vanilla implementation and neither my UITableViewController nor any other superview is doing anything to the bounds.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation for UITableView's selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: has a section that describes what you are experiencing.

> Special Considerations Passing UITableViewScrollPositionNone will
>   result in no scrolling, rather than the minimum scrolling described
>   for that constant. To scroll to the newly selected row with minimum
>   scrolling, select the row using this method with
>   UITableViewScrollPositionNone, then call
>   scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: with
>   UITableViewScrollPositionNone.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the table view's content view has the space to scroll. I once need to scroll the table view because user tap on a text field and the keyboard came up, I need the extend the table view's content to the height of the keyboard's height so that the table view can scroll. Like this:

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardFrame.size.height, 0.0);
self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.currentEditingCellIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```